# Why are these buttons not lined up vertically? Is there something wrong with my css?

Tags: html, css

I have this code with two buttons that have images inside them:

```css
.btn {
  color: black;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 75px;
  max-height: 75px;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  transition: 250ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  transition: 250ms;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: 250ms;
}

button.settings {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<div>
  <button class="btn"><img style="width: 25px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waterlava/dice-roller/f775e3565babbc898b00120dcac798bc78c94d46/Dice/d4.svg"><br>d4</button>
  <button class="btn"><img style="width: 25px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waterlava/dice-roller/f775e3565babbc898b00120dcac798bc78c94d46/Dice/d6.svg"><br>d6</button>
</div>
```

My question is why aren't the buttons lined up vertically? Should I change something in my css?

Comment: vertical-align:top

Answer (score 1):

html buttons by default are displayed as inline-block. So you could either set the display value of the parent container (as I have done in this example) to flex and give it a flex-direction of column. Or, you could set the button display to something like block, so that they take up the entire width of the container.

Lots of ways to fix it.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.btn {
  color: black;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 75px;
  max-height: 75px;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  transition: 250ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  transition: 250ms;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: 250ms;
}

button.settings {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<div class="wrapper">
  <button class="btn"><img style="width: 25px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waterlava/dice-roller/f775e3565babbc898b00120dcac798bc78c94d46/Dice/d4.svg"><br>d4</button>
  <button class="btn"><img style="width: 25px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waterlava/dice-roller/f775e3565babbc898b00120dcac798bc78c94d46/Dice/d6.svg"><br>d6</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the parent container to `display:flex;` and use the default setting for displaying in an x-axis. It's hard to say what's causing the issue as you are linking to an external css file.

```css
#even {
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  color: black;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 75px;
  max-height: 75px;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  transition: 250ms;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  transition: 250ms;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.95);
  transition: 250ms;
}

button.settings {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
<div id="even">
  <button class="btn"><img style="width: 25px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waterlava/dice-roller/f775e3565babbc898b00120dcac798bc78c94d46/Dice/d4.svg"><br>d4</button>
  <button class="btn"><img style="width: 25px" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waterlava/dice-roller/f775e3565babbc898b00120dcac798bc78c94d46/Dice/d6.svg"><br>d6</button>
</div>
```